# Converting a locale date to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, localisation, date

I have a datepicker in my site which formats the time in the current locale. So the time gets sent to the server in `d/MM/yy`-format.

The locale on the frontend is determined by `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface::getDateFormat()`.

Now how can I convert this date to a database-friendly datetime (`YYYY-MM-DD`) or at least to a timestamp of some sort?

So basically I'm looking for a clean generic approach on how to convert a localized date to a timestamp.

I've tried all kind of things but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my own question:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
 */
protected $localeResolver;

... some code ...

$newDate = date('Y-m-d', (new \IntlDateFormatter(
    $this->localeResolver->getLocale(),
    \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    \IntlDateFormatter::NONE
))->parse($localizeDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me but directly using object manager is not a good way inject TimezoneInterface into your constructor:

```
 $date = "1991-12-19 00:00:00"
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $timezoneInterface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');
 $formattedDate = $timezoneInterface->date($date)->format('Y/m/d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 and 1 are all PHP based, you could use the native (quicker) PHP function to get this without having to add more into your __constructs or using ObjectManager (which can be heavy):

1) Get today's date formatted:

> $todayDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

2) Get a specific date formatted:

> $MyDate = date_create("2020-04-08");
>
> $MyDateFormatted = date_format($MyDate, "Y/m/d H:i:s");

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure the date is converted to internal format.**
For example `created_at` date need to converted from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-DD`.
So we have to use `$this->_dateFilter` object of `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date` Class and then use `Zend_Filter_Input()` function to convert to internal format. If `$data['created_at'] = '07/27/2021';` after conversion to internal format `created_at` date will be `$data['created_at'] = '2021-07-27';`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\MyController;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    /**
     * Date filter instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date
     */
    protected $_dateFilter;

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\Repository\MyModelRepository $myModel
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Repository\MyModelRepository $myModel, 
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_myModel = $myModel;
        $this->_dateFilter = $dateFilter;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        // make sure the date is converted to internal format
        $filterValues = ['created_at' => $this->_dateFilter];

        $inputFilter = new \Zend_Filter_Input($filterValues, [], $data);

        $data = $inputFilter->getUnescaped();


        $model = $this->_myModel();

        $model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
           echo  $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }

}
```